# Dragula angular how to access the model item

Tags: angularjs, dragula, angular-dragula

How do I access the exact model item that was dragged and dropped using the drop-model event?

Description of the drop event from the docs:

> **el** was dropped into **target** before a **sibling** element, and originally came from **source**

**el** seems to return the HTML element that was dragged but I need to perform actions on the actual data item behind it. Any hints?

```
 <div class="collapse" id="manageUsers">
    <div class='containerDragula' dragula='"bag"' dragula-model='usersInProject'>
        <div ng-repeat='user in usersInProject' ng-bind='user.email'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='containerDragula' dragula='"bag"' dragula-model='usersNotInProject'>
        <div ng-repeat='user in usersNotInProject' ng-bind='user.email'></div>
    </div>
</div>

$scope.$on('bag.drop-model', function (e, el, target, source) {
    //this returns the html element
    console.log(el);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding the id of the item to the HTML element.

Something like this:

```
<div id="{{ user.id }}" ng-repeat='user in usersNotInProject' ng-bind='user.email'></div>
```

In the controller I look up the item using the id:

```
$scope.$on('bag.drop-model', function (e, el, target, source) {
    //getById is a function you implement (unless you already have it)
    console.log(usersNotInProject.getById(el.attr('id')).email);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this clever way to do it

Comment: I did similarly. Shame the lib doesn't have it in the first place. For ng2 it was requested and included